# Как сделать группировку в mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Есть коллекция с документами вида:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"),
    "title" : "test title",
    "category" : "test category",
    "pubDate" : "1457599100",
    "code" : "ZZZ"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"),
    "title" : "test 2 title",
    "category" : "test 2 category",
    "pubDate" : "1457599200",
    "code" : "ZZZ"
}
```

Как сделать группировку, чтобы получить на выходе что-то типа этого:

```
{
  "ZZZ": {
    "items": {
      0:{
         "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"),
         "title" : "test title",
         "category" : "test category",
         "pubDate" : "1457599100"
      },
      1:{
         "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"),
         "title" : "test 2 title",
         "category" : "test 2 category",
         "pubDate" : "1457599100"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [**Aggregation Framework**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) и оператор [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: "$code",
            "items":
            {
                $push:
                {
                    "_id": "$_id",
                     "title": "$title",
                     "category": "$category",
                     "pubDate": "$pubDate"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Результат запроса:

```
[ 
    {
        "_id" : "ZZZ",
        "items" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8b459b"),
                "title" : "test title",
                "category" : "test category",
                "pubDate" : "1457599100"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("56e17f2db292c9151a8a459b"),
                "title" : "test 2 title",
                "category" : "test 2 category",
                "pubDate" : "1457599200"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Полученный результат слегка отличается от запрошенного, но, в целом, можно настроить его, поработав с [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).